# Identical built-in function

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a built-in function in Python 3 for the function `lambda x: x`? Sometimes it may make some code more elegant. For example:

```
def my_sort(lst, key):
    ...

lst = [4, 3, 7, 1, 9]
my_sort(lst, key=lambda x: x)   # probably it can be written in a better way WITHOUT lambda x: x with the help of a standard function
```

I need a build-in or standard function in Python 3, not an expression like `lambda x: x` of a different way to improve my code.

Comment: `key=None`?.... Why even have a key?

Comment: @COLDSPEED `None` is not a function.

Comment: You asked for something that is more elegant... what else do you want? `lambda x: x` happens to be the identity function which `None` expertly mimics.

Comment: You still haven't explained your reason/purpose for doing this, I don't see the reason for an identity function.

Comment: Remember, you could just do `def my_sort(lst, key=None):` and neglect to pass `key` so the default is implied, indeed that's how `sorted` is defined.

Comment: Perhaps you should show us a better example that illustrates where an identity function would actually be useful. FWIW, there's nothing wrong with `lambda x: x` if it does the job (although it isn't as fast as a function coded in C would be), and the function you're passing it to doesn't accept a special value like `None` to indicate that it should use the identity function.

Comment: I guess you could do `identity=functools.partial(lambda x: x)`. :)

Comment: My question is correct. I'm asking for a Python standard function, like `operator.getitem(0)`, or a build-in function to make my code more elegant than `lambda x: x`.

Comment: That would imply performing some kind of _operation_ on the input, which you're not doing. You basically want to find another way to do `def f(x): return x`. There really isn't.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, @pm-2ring commented way using `partial` seems well enough for doing an identity function

Comment: @DanielSanchez It's still a wrapper around the lambda... and at that point you might as well define `def f(x): return x` and pass `f` to `my_sort`, right?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, yep, actually `def identity(x) : return x` seems pretty legit. you are 100% right :)

Answer (score 1):

A pythonic approach would be to use a default argument of `None` that makes `key` optional:

```
def my_sort(lst, key=None):
    if key is None:
        key = lambda x: x
    ...

lst = [4, 3, 7, 1, 9]
my_sort(lst)
```

Comment: You can even shorten the key declaration as `key = key or (lambda x: x)`. Not what some people would prefer though :).

Comment: def my_sort(lst, key = lambda x:x), is also possible, right?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, please, read my question carefully.

Comment: @stack_n_queue `None` makes it look more like the built-in `sorted`: `sorted(iterable, /, *, key=None, reverse=False)`.